# UIWebView taking up all avaialble space inside UiNavigationController

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UiWebView that is accessed via a UiNavigation controller. In its view the toolbar is visible and the navigation bar is hidden.

I am trying to get the WebView to take up all the available space. I found this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    //make sure web view takes up all space
    self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

This seems to work, but I would like to do this without using code and have it work for 3.5in and 4in screens.

Is this possible?

Comment: sure, use auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `AutoresizingMask` property of the webview to flexible width and height.

```
webview.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```